# How do I delete multiple rows from a GridView using Checkboxes and a Button?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010, button

My code is as follows. I am not storing my data in a database. I'm just extracting the data from the TextBox, and displaying it in a GridView. How do I delete multiple rows from a GridView using Checkboxes and a Button? 
**//code for deleting the row**

**ASPX Code:**

```
 <asp:TemplateField>
 <ItemTemplate>
 <asp:CheckBox ID="chkdelete" runat="server" />
 </ItemTemplate>
 </asp:TemplateField>
```

**C# code:**

```
protected void btnDelete_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Loop through all the rows in gridview
    foreach(GridViewRow gvrow in gvUserDetails.Rows)
    {
        //Finiding checkbox control in gridview for particular row
        CheckBox chkdelete = (CheckBox)gvrow.FindControl("chkdelete");
        //Condition to check checkbox selected or not
        if(chkdelete.Checked)
        {
            //code for deleting the row    (What code do I write here?)
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to basically delete the rows in the database or any such thing from where you have bound the gridview. So delete all the rows, create new DataSource and bind the gridview again and it should work like a charm.

UPDATE: As you are not using any database, still you would definitly have some datasource with which you bound your gridview, so modify that and bind the gridview again.

Answer (score 0):

If a GridView works like a DataGridView, then a simple `GridView.Rows.RemoveAt(index)` should do what you want.

EDIT: In this case, you would not want to do a *foreach* but a `for(int loop=GridView.Rows.Count - 1; loop>=0; loop--)`, instead.